# Since the compiler calls a method based on the reference type and not the actual object type, why does the object's method get called?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Code:

```
public class X
{
    public void methodA() //Base class method
    {
        System.out.println ("hello, I'm methodA of class X");
    } 
}

public class Y extends X
{
    public void methodA() //Derived Class method
    {
        System.out.println ("hello, I'm methodA of class Y");
    }
}

public class Z
{
   public static void main (String args []) {
       X obj1 = new X(); // Reference and object X
       X obj2 = new Y(); // X reference but Y object
       obj1.methodA();
       obj2.methodA();
   }
}
```

Output:

```
hello, I'm methodA of class X
hello, I'm methodA of class Y
```

The method from the object type is getting called instead of the reference type. Isn't the out put in both lines supposed to be this?

```
hello, I'm methodA of class X
hello, I'm methodA of class X
```

Comment: Maybe your first assumption is wrong... which is fun, considering you are correctly tagging your question with [tag:polymorphism]

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my bad. I meant that the compiler decides whether we can call the method.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler chooses a method signature that best matches the method call (out of all the overloaded methods having the same name which are available for the compile time type of the variable for which the method is called).

However, the method that actually gets executed is only determined at runtime, based on the run time type of the instance refered by the variable for which the method is called. That's what method overriding means.'

You may be confusing method overloading (done at compile time) with method overriding (done at run time).

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious. when you declare `methodA()` again in subclass. The `methodA()` of super class is overridden. So now whenever you call `methodA()`, the `methodA()` of subclass will be called.

```
X obj1 = new Y();
Y obj2 = new Y();
obj1.methodA();
((X)obj2).methodA();
```

both will call the overriden method.

In java there is no way to call the method which is overridden. Only the thing you can do to call superclass's method while overriding a function is this :

```
public void methodA() { //Derived Class method
    super.methodA();
    // add other stuff if you want here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java uses 'early binding', i.e. associating a name to a method during compilation, and 'dynamic dispatch', selecting the method implementation most closely associated with the object's type at runtime. 
Java uses the reference type when binding because the object's type may not be known during compilation.

```
X obj1 = new X();    // obj1 is bound to X and of type X
if (i == 0) {
     obj1 = new Y(); // obj1 is still bound to X, but now of type Y
}
obj1.methodA();      
// Due to early binding, a compiler error occurs if X doesn't contain methodA
// Due to dynamic dispatch, if it exists, the methodA of obj1's type will be used. Otherwise the closest superclass's methodA will be used.
```